# Converting a json file which has first been converted to an Observable, to a map in typescript, in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, observable

I have a json file - dummy, which which looks like this -

```
[
    {"key":"KEY1", "value":["alpha","beta","gamma"]},

    {"key":"KEY2", "value":["A","B","C"]},

    {"key":"KEY3", "value":["One","Foo","Bar"]}
]
```

I wanted to convert this json file to a map with key- value pairs same as given in the json file.

To achieve this I created an observable - myObservable first, and did something like this in the component.ts file -

```
myMap: any = {};
myObservable: Observable<any> = Observable.of(this.dummy);

getObservable() {
    return this.myObservable;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getObservable()
    .subscribe(myResponse => {
        this.myMap = new Map(myResponse); //Converting myresponse to map here.
    )}.
```

But this analogy failed to work. How do I convert this observable file to a map in typescript?

Expected Output:

```
{
    Key1,[alpha,beta,gamma]
    Key2,[A,B,C]
    Key3,[One,Foo,Bar]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post more details on the error you are getting (e. g. by pasting the error message) as it will be easier to help you then. Cheers :)

Comment: Please provide your expected output

Comment: I have added the expected output

Comment: I wanted to convert the myResponse variable to a map

Comment: I believe you need to do something like `.subscribe( res => { let myResponse = res.json(); }) `

Comment: TypeError: res.json is not a function is showing, if I implement this

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dummy = [

     {"key":"KEY1", "value":["alpha","beta","gamma"]},

     {"key":"KEY2", "value":["A","B","C"]},

     {"key":"KEY3", "value":["One","Foo","Bar"]}
 ]
 
 const result = new Map();
 
 dummy.map(item => {

 result.set(item["key"], item["value"]);
 })
 
for (var [key, value] of result.entries()) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```